# Reading a JSON output

Tags: c#, json

Am new to C# and I have an HTTP response which i have converted to a json object via

```
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
```

When i `Debug.WriteLine((object)jsonResponse);` am now getting

```
{
    "status": false,
    "data": 
    {
        "message": "Incorrect Username or Password",
        "name": "Failed Login"
    }
}
```

Which is as i expect. But the problem comes in reading it i have tried

```
if ((object)jsonResponse.status != true){ //throws an error
       ...do stuff
 }
```

The above if statement throws an error

> the operand != cannot be applied to operands of type boolean and object

by altering the code and adding

```
if ((bool)(object)jsonResponse.status != true){ //throws an error
       ...do stuff
 }
```

the above throws an error

> Unable to cast object of type NewtonSoft.Json.Linq.Jvalue to  system.boolean

What else do i need to add?

but when i run

```
Debug.WriteLine((object)jsonResponse.status)
```

the value is true.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Any reasons that you can't create a class and deserialize your response into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add classes for your response

```
public class Data
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class LoginResponse
{
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

then convert response to class

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponse>(result);
```

and use it

```
if(!response.status){
//do staff
}
```

Comment: `!= true` aka `!`.

Comment: @Geomdev Don't forget to mark it as answer if it helped tho.

Answer (score 1):

Create classes and deserialize response to it:

```
public class Data
{
    public string message {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}

public class Response
{
    public bool status {get;set;}
    public Data data {get;set;}
}

var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(result);

if (!jsonResponse.status){
   //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to read a `Json`. You can access them one by one, along the way as you come down reading the file.

As in your code below:

```
{
 "status": false,
 "data": {
      "message": "Incorrect Username or Password",
      "name": "Failed Login"
 }
}
```

You will need to access it like this:

```
JsonObject json = JsonObject.Parse(data);
var statusObject = json.GetNamedBoolean("status");
var dataObject = json.GetNamedObject("data");
var message = dataObject.GetNamedString("message");
var name = dataObject.GetNamedString("name");

// if you need to check whether the `Json` contains the object or not
// check it with
if (dataObject.ContainsKey("message"))
{
    // get the value here as above
}
```